# Need to get the list of currently running applications visible to the user on MAC

Tags: macos, window, nsworkspace

I am developing in MAC and need to get the list of all the active applications currently running, I mean the ones which have actual window and the user can see/close/minimize/maximize.

I tried using NSWorkspace runningApplications function, but it gives a long list of applications (most probably it also lists some hidden applications) but I need only the ones that has window UI.

I've also used the suggestion in the following post to get the windows below the Dock and it worked fine in case if the Dock is visible:
[CGWindowListCreate generates a hugely long list of windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11150859/cgwindowlistcreate-generates-a-hugely-long-list-of-windows)

However when the Dock is hidden this solution doesn't work.

Does anyone have any idea how to get the list of running applications visible to user on MAC?

Answer (score 0):

It may help you. Try this

```
for (NSRunningApplication *app in [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] runningApplications]) {
        NSLog(@"%@",[app localizedName]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

void ListWindows()
{
    NSMutableArray* windows = 
         (__bridge NSMutableArray *)CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo(
                                         kCGWindowListOptionOnScreenOnly | 
                                         kCGWindowListExcludeDesktopElements, 
                                         kCGNullWindowID);

    for (NSDictionary* window in windows) {
        if([[window objectForKey:@"kCGWindowLayer" ] intValue] == 0)
        {
        NSLog(@"%@", [window objectForKey:@"kCGWindowOwnerName"]);
        }
    }

}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
  NSLog(@"Active windows:");
  ListWindows();
  return 0;
}
```

Sample output :

```
Active windows: 
Xcode 
TextEdit 
Finder
```